# Is there a way to access data inside tkinter widgets by their location in the grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to create a table which consists of many entry and drop down lists. The amount of rows of this list is dynamic and rows are added by the user. After the user has finished his list he needs to press the "Run" button and then I would like to access each entry\dropdown list and access the data within it. Is there a way to do it? Maybe by accessing the widgets grid location?

Comment: It'd be much easier to just put the widgets into a list or dict while you're creating the form, and access them from there afterwards. Please show your code?

Comment: Each time you add a new widget, I'd add it to a dictionary where the key is a tuple which contains the row/column identifier, for example: `myWidgets[(row,column)] = tk.Button(frame, text="Hello")`. Then when you need to access the widget just look for that value in the dictionary. For a more precise answer, you would need to share an example of your code.